# Chrome extension: create window and disallow moving it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window

I know how to use the [chrome API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) to create a small window that will be located in the center of the screen.

Is there a way to prevent moving this window?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect not, as it's outside the scope of Chrome and would be controlled by the OS itself.